# Deploy asp.net core microservice application to GKE from VS 2019 using Google Cloud Tool

Tags: google-cloud-platform, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine, asp.net-core-3.1, google-cloud-tools

I have tried to deploy a asp.net core microservice application to GKE from VS 2019 using Google cloud tool as per the documentation mentioned on the link https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/deployment-wizard.

But I have found the disabled Publish button. Please find the screenshot below. Can you please share which service need to be enabled for this? I have already enabled GKE, Container Registry and created the cluster.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please change the image, because this contains the Project ID, this is to avoid any security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s really helpful if you follow the instructions shared on the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart) to deploy this tool with visual studio.

You need to [enable the following APIs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started).

- App Engine Admin API
- Google App Engine Flexible Environment
- Cloud Build API

[This APIs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/access-control#before_you_begin) will enable this push button.

Also, the [Google Cloud SDK installer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#windows) lets you download, install and set up the latest version of Cloud SDK quickly in an interactive mode. When you run the installer, it downloads Cloud SDK components and installs them on the local system.

BR.

Comment: This Works! Thanks a lot!